# Run Publishing.Administration - method as a Farm Admin

Tags: 2010, permissions, administration, content-deployment, jobs

I need to call a method from publishing.administration-Namespace as a farm admin. To be specific: `ContentDeploymentJob.GetAllJobs();`

When I try to run that code I get the exception that the code can only be run by farm administrators.

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` does not help. Also running under the System Accounts SPUserToken Like 'SPSite("myWebsite.com",SPUserToken.SystemAccount)' is of no help, because I am not in a SPSite-Context

Which ways are there to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found out that can not be done in a normal SiteCollection. You have to create a timerjob to read and start Content-Deployments and then communicate with you Site Collection